# Set default parameter value in function to value of another parameter

Tags: python, default-arguments

Is there a way to set a default parameter value in a function to be another one of the parameters?

I.e.

```
def (input1, input2 = input1)
```

I figure I can do something like what’s shown below, but want to know if there’s a better way

```
def (input1, input2 = 'blank')
      If input2 == 'blank':
           input2 = input1
```

Comment: No you can't, because at the declaration of `input2=input1`, `input1` needs to be already defined

Comment: @bdbd Not true. Go test it.

Comment: @PeterJones Tested `def test(x, y=x):`. It says `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`, so you can't

Answer (score 3):

You could try this. Maybe a little more clarification could help us help you more.

```
def do_stuff(input1, input2 = None):
    if input2 is None:
       input2 = input1
```

You were pretty close.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign a local variable to an argument, as the variable is not yet defined during the definition of the function.

We usually use `None` to catch a missing value:

```
def add2(i1, i2=None):
    if i2 is None:
        i2 = i1
    return i1 + i2
```

In this function, `i1` will be mandatory. If not provided, `i2` will be set to the same value as `i1`.

```
add2(10, 2)
# > 12
add2(9)
# > 18
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use create a class as the parameter

```
class helper:
    input 2 = 'blank'
    input 3 = 1
def xx(input1, helper):
    if input1 == helper.input2:
        input1 == helper.input3
```

This is an example, you can use a class to help you.